# Is there a performance difference between `=` and `<=>`?

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization

I've recently changed all my where conditions to use `<=>` instead of `=` because I need to check against nulls. Are there any performance concerns?

Answer (score 2):

There is no real performance impact here is a test to verify for yourself

```
mysql> SELECT BENCHMARK(1000000, (SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE userId FROM Activity WHERE userId<=>42459204 LIMIT 1));
```

Make sure that you need to use <=>

> NULL-safe equal. This operator
>   performs an equality comparison like
>   the = operator, but returns 1 rather
>   than NULL if both operands are NULL,
>   and 0 rather than NULL if one operand
>   is NULL.

If you just need to check the rvalue do

col=CONST AND CONST IS NOT NULL

or t1.col=t2.col

Comment: It's for my DB abstraction layer. You can pass in a dictionary of column-value pairs, and it should check that that column is equal to that value. Null is a valid value.

Answer (score 1):

`<=>` is basically a shortcut to include `OR (Val1 IS NULL AND Val2 IS NULL)` or `IS NOT DISTINCT FROM`

It *is* an additional operation but the difference should be negligible **unless** you are `SELECT`ing the data to be compared because otherwise the first `SELECT` returning `NULL` doesn't need to execute the second `SELECT` because the standard equality operator `=` will always yield false.

As @Dathan noted, make sure this is actually when you intend to do.